# Rename folder to two destination folders on SFTP server with PHP

Tags: php, sftp

This function is working and move folders from mainfolder to one folder called `destinationfolder1`. I want to move the folders to one other folder also. Folder called `backup`, what is in the same place/level as `destinationfolder1`. Is this possible?

```
ssh2_sftp_rename($sftp, 'mainfolder/' . $entry  , 'destinationfolder1/' . $entry );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "rename" a file/folder to two folders. That's nonsense. You have to create a copy of the file/folder.

There's no "copy" function in a core SFTP protocol. There's `copy-file` SFTP extension for this. But it's not supported by PHP SSH2 functions. You might be able to add the extension to open source [phpseclib library](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). But actually very few SFTP servers do support the extension. In the most widespread OpenSSH SFTP server it is supported only by very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0).

If you have a shell access to the server, as a workaround, you can just execute `cp` shell command using [`ssh2_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php):

```
ssh2_exec($connection, 'cp -r /source/path/file /backup/file');
```

If you do not have a shell access, your only option is to download the file/folder and re-upload it to the other folder.

---

See also [In an SFTP session is it possible to copy one remote file to another location on same remote SFTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26260056/850848)