# SSH.NET SftpClient: Copy / Duplicate SftpFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sftp, ssh.net

Is there a way to copy a file in an other directory like a copy/paste.
`.MoveTo()` method move only the SftpFile and I tried `WriteAllBytes()` method using `SftpFile.Attribues.GetBytes()`, but it writes always a corrupted file.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will hardly be able to copy the file directly. For details why, see:
[In an SFTP session is it possible to copy one remote file to another location on same remote SFTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26260056/850848)

---

So you have to download and re-upload the file.

The easiest way to do that (without creating a temporary local file) is:

```
SftpClient client = new SftpClient("exampl.com", "username", "password");
client.Connect();

using (Stream sourceStream = client.OpenRead("/source/path/file.dat"))
using (Stream destStream = client.Create("/dest/path/file.dat"))
{
    sourceStream.CopyTo(destStream);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to copy remote file to new one:

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
{
  client.Connect();

  using (Stream sourceStream = sftp.OpenRead(remoteFile))
  {
     sftp.UploadFile(sourceStream, remoteFileNew));
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your answer show on top of my existing answer?